# javascript running in nodejs v.s. web browser, about variable scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

In browser, diffrent javascript file share one scope:

> a.js:
>
> var a=1; //we add "var", so we not intent it be a global var.
>
> b.js:
>
> console.log(a) //a=1, but b.js can also see this var!

In nodejs:

> a.js ....
>
> b.js ....
>
> console.log(a)// b.js cannot see the var, declare by "var" keywork

is there any doc say those difference ?

Comment: `var a=1` does not make a not global variable (in browser), it depends on where you put this declaration (scope)

Comment: in file beginning,not in a funciton

Comment: So on global scope.. (browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nodejs encapsulates scope per file, sort of like ruby. If you want to share variables you should `export` them:

file1.js:

```
exports.a = 5;
```

file2.js:

```
exports.b = 6;
```

main.js:

```
var file1 = require('./file1.js');
var file2 = require('./file2.js');
console.log(file1.a); // 5
console.log(file2.b); // 6
```

Anything you export in a file by assigning to `export.variablename = yourObject;` will be accessible when you include the file from elsewhere: `var exportedStuff = require('./file.js')` would let you access `yourObject` at `exportedStuff.variablename`.

The reason for all of this is to force you to be more organized about how you write your code. As opposed to just slapping global variables around everywhere, it forces you to organize your code into modules, and also gives you the ability to emulate private scoping in an easier way than on the web.

In the web when you omit `var`, and just have `varname = 5` then when variable does not already exist, it's the same as saying `window.varname`. This is NOT the case in nodejs. In Node if you want to use global you must do global.varname = 5

Comment: but, just like browser, if you dont add any "var" in a variable, then all var can see each other. this confuse me.

Comment: actually, if you dont prefix a var in js file A, then even in nodejs, js file B also can see this var. I have make a test, in my first nodejs project. windows7, and a recent nodejs version

Answer (score 2):

that is correct. All of the files are loaded in the browser combined but in node.js uses modules per file so basically to combine the files from b.js you need to do

`var a=require('a.js');`

then your variable will be in *a.a*

for this to work you need to `exports.a=1` in a.js

Be sure to keep in your mind that while javascript is the same language, different programming techniques are used in frontend and backend.